# Jupyter notebook throwing "connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time..:" error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have created a function below. This function works well and instantly in my VScode terminal. However when I import this function into a jupyter notebook and try to execute from there, I get an error *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.* There also is an error about the output file size limit which is strange as the list being outputed is quite small. I can confirm that the issue exists in ipython as well so it's a ipython/jupyter limitation. I have tried adding a decent timeout in the http call but to no avail.

```
def list_all_workspaces(url, headers, path):
    
  payload = json.dumps({
    "path": f"{path}"
  })
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=20000)
  json_response = json.loads(response.text)
  try:
    objects = json_response['objects']
    object_path_list = [object['path'] for object in objects]
    return object_path_list
  except Exception as e:
    return []
```

[image]

Comment: @MiH - I don't think your answers are related to my question at all. I can't switch to a POST request when the API endpoint I'm reaching out to prescribes a GET request. Moreover there is nothing wrong with the mechanism of the API call itself.

Comment: I suggest you debug line by line on Jupyter Notebook (1) check `payload = json.dumps(...)` (2) check `requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)` (3) check `json_response.json()` (4) check `json_response['objects']`. If you can print these outputs in the question, the community can help to debug